# Understanding when we need injectivity requirement for substitution in integrals and when not and why

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am expanding my query i asked before so as to get a more well explained reasoning for this :. Suppose we are required to evaluate three integrals :

1. $\int_{0}^{4} \frac{2x-4}{x^2 - 4x  + 5}dx$
2. $\int_{0}^{4} \frac{lnx}{√(4x-x^2)}dx$
3. $\int_{0}^{5} \frac{lnx}{√4x-x^2} dx$.

> For first one i have two methods

- method 1 : injectivity substitution keeping in mind i am able to split it into two separate integrate limits and evaluate both integrals whose sum gives it value = 0 , but interestingly the second method which do not used injectivity gives directly the upper and lower limit as same , after letting $(x-2)^2 = t$ . Although its not necessary that limits being same after substitution implies integral being zero , but if the form of the integral is $\frac{f'(x)}{f^2(x)}$  it suprisingly always works!!! Without injectivity condition needed , i would like to know why is that true in the above integrand form .
- As such for 2nd integral if we use the injectivity method again , we will get sum to be zero , but without injectivity  it again works out true . Same question why it works here too ? I thought as such this integral is improper there might be some changes needed in the conditions but it turn out it works here too why ?
- For third one its one side improper integral , but still the exact same reasoning because finally the evaluation is based only on the 5 and 0 value why ?

> Few points i ponder over : if we happen to have $\int_{0}^{4} \frac{1}{4x-x^2 +1}dx $ it turns out here the limits of the integral being same after substitution does not work since integral value is $1.2912..$ >0 , so from this i think f'(x) contribution is a major factor playing some **very hidden role** here  for the first integral. So it seems like this special trick might also always happens in integrals of form $\frac{f'(x)}{f^n(x)}$ , $n \geq 1$ and like some integrals which are as in the fork of 2nd integral . Is it true ?